# Promise.resolve() potential redundancy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am working on an existing Restify API that has a lot of this:

```
return newPromise().then(function(){

   return Promise.resolve({foo:'bar'});
}).then(function(){

  return Promise.resolve({rolo:'cholo'});
}):
```

now, returning `Promise.resolve` inside a promise is definitely unnecessary, but I am wondering it is not only redundant, but if it is hurting the API performance because ultimately `Promise.resolve` may be called twice on the same value.

So my question is - are ES6 native promises optimized so that they will not try to resolve a promise that is already resolved? In other words, does the internal API avoid calling `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(x))`?

Comment: this is a good question, downvote not appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak of any implementations, but the ES6 spec [seems to have a bug](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/don-t-test-promise-results-on-their-thenability-multiple-times) that *requires* promises and their result values to be resolved every single time.

Comment: interesting, thanks Bergi, I would have expected Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(x))) to be idempotent, but maybe it's not, yikes

Comment: @AlexMills `Promise.resolve()` is actually not involved in promise resolution.

Comment: @jib: `Promise.resolve` does exactly the same thing as [`PromiseCabability.[[resolve]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) that is used for promise resolution, so calling `Promise.resolve` on the return value of a `then` callback will run the same algorithm twice.

Comment: @Bergi How is that the same as http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve ? Also, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37848356/918910).

Comment: @jib: Oh, right, I always forget about that part with the `isPromise`, so `x = Promise.resolve(…); x === Promise.resolve(x)` indeed. But `new Promise(resolve => resolve(Promise.resolve(x)))` or `promise.then(()=>Promise.resolve(x))` will indeed try to resolve `x` twice.

Comment: @Bergi Assuming `x` is a promise, then I don't see how, given that `Promise.resolve(x)` is just a function that returns `x` in that case, a no-op. Given that `x` may in fact never resolve in this example (f.ex: `var x = new Promise(() => {});`), it's hard to see how `Promise.resolve` has anything to do with `x`'s resolution.

Comment: @jib: I meant when `x` is not a promise, but an arbitrary object, then it's thenability will be tested multiple times. Maybe I should've used two distinct variable names, yeah…

Comment: @AlexMills `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1))` is not unlike `[[1]]`. It's a value wrapped in two Functors (containers).

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the internal implementation, but <s>the performance characteristics look roughly equivalent</s> **returning values directly is about 2x faster for Native Promises and 1.1x faster for Bluebird**. Here's a benchmark script I wrote:

**Bluebird**

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
suite
.add('Inner Resolve', {
    name: "Bluebird Inner Resolve",
    defer: true,
    fn: function (deferred) {
        return Promise.resolve("a")
            .then(() => Promise.resolve("b"))
            .then(() => deferred.resolve());
    }
})
.add('Bluebird Inner Return', {
    name: "Bluebird Inner Return",
    defer: true,
    fn: function (deferred) {
        return Promise.resolve("a")
            .then(() => "b")
            .then(() => deferred.resolve());
    }
})
.on('cycle', (event) => console.log(String(event.target)))
.on('complete', function onComplete () {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
.run({ 'async': true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.0/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

**Native:**

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
suite
.add('Native Inner Resolve', {
    name: "Native Inner Resolve",
    defer: true,
    fn: function (deferred) {
        return Promise.resolve("a")
            .then(() => Promise.resolve("b"))
            .then(() => deferred.resolve());
    }
})
.add('Native Inner Return', {
    name: "Native Inner Return",
    defer: true,
    fn: function (deferred) {
        return Promise.resolve("a")
            .then(() => "b")
            .then(() => deferred.resolve());
    }
})
.on('cycle', (event) => console.log(String(event.target)))
.on('complete', function onComplete () {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
.run({ 'async': true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.0/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

You can look at Chrome's implementation here (https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4.3.66/src/promise.js#L167); some bookkeeping appears to be done in Promise.resolve, but it's not significantly affecting perf.

Comment: Benchmark.js doesn't support promises, so you should make the tests deferred. It looks like _"Native InnerResolve"_ is significantly slower than _"Native InnerReturn"_ when compared with Bluebird's counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; the results make more sense now. The native innerResolve is much slower

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.resolve()` is a helper function with a limited purpose, so I wouldn't read too much into its behavior or performance, or relate that to what goes on under the hood during promise chaining or resolution in implementations.

FWIW, in all browser implementations I tried (including Safari), I find that the following holds true:

```js
var p = new Promise(function() {});

console.log(Promise.resolve(p) == p);
```

Which means it does little more than return what's passed in, when passed a promise. Redundant code is never free in JS, but this is minimal.

It also means it has zero impact later during resolution, since it doesn't contribute additional promises to a resolution-chain.

Turns out this behavior is [explicitly specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve) (*If IsPromise(x) return x;* basically).

We should shun calling `Promise.resolve()` needlessly because it is redundant, not because of any real performance concern.